# Update textarea after submit to SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

I'm writting a page which has a 'Personal Notes' section using textarea. When I click at 'Save' it actually saves the content to an SQL server but then it displays the old notes information at textarea. What I need it to update the textarea whit the new information after submit.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$userlevel = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT level FROM users WHERE username = '$user_check'");

$ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userlevel);

if ($ar['level'] == '0')
{
    $level = "Utilizador";
}
else
{
    $level = "Administrador";
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $savenotes = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['notes']);
    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE users SET notes = '$savenotes' WHERE username = '$username'");
    $msg = "Notas pessoais guardadas no servidor.";
}
?>

<div style = "margin:30px">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" onClick="location.href='main.php?action=home'">Home</a></li>
        <li><a onClick="location.href='main.php?action=servers'">Servidores</a></li>
        <li><a onClick="location.href='main.php?action=users'">Utilizadores</a></li>
        <li><a onClick="location.href='main.php?action=account'">Minha Conta</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a onClick="location.href='logout.php'">Sair</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a><b>Acesso:</b> <font color=red><?php echo $level; ?></font></a></li>
    </ul>
    <br><br>

<font size=5><b>Bem-vindo, <?php echo utf8_encode($login_session); ?><br /></b></font><br />
Por favor escolha uma das opções do painel para gerir este servidor. Pode adicionar/remover/alterar servidores de jogo e voz bem como utilizadores deste painel.<br />
Qualquer bug ou sugestão contactar mail@mail.com.<br /><br />

Notas Pessoais:<br />
<form action = "" method = "post">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type ="text" name ="notes" style="border-radius: 4px; border: solid 1px light-gray; box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0 #009AFC0; transition: box-shadow 0.3s;";/><?php echo htmlentities($notes);?></textarea><br /><br />
    <button  class="button" type = "submit" style="vertical-align:middle; width:100px;"><span>Gravar </span></button><br />
</form>
<div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As per the given code snippet, looks like `$notes` is not being set anywhere. So, `echo`-ing  `$savenotes` should show you the new contents. However, this could cause you problems if `$notes` is set elsewhere in the code and contains some pre-filled data to be shown when the page is presented. As an aside, please have a look at [MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to write secure scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load `$notes` after insert.

Right now it's not clear where you load it, but it should be loaded after insert.

Comment: Hello. $notes is defined in sessions.php where is stored all session information. So how can I load that var after submit without refreshing the page?

Comment: So you fetched notes before storing to a session - fetch them again after insert to database.